# Python - Creating a Nested List with value using One line code

Tags: python, arrays, list, nested

I want to create a nested list in one line. List will be:

```
a = [["-","-",..."-"],["-","-",..."-"],...["-","-",..."-"]]
```

Each inner list should have 10 "-"s and the nested list should have 10 lists in it.

I've tried that one but it does not work as i wanted:

```
a = ["-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"]*10

print(a)
```

Output was:

```
['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should produce a nested list as expected:

#### Code:

```
a = [["-"]*10]*10
print(a)
```

#### Output:

```
[['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Not in refrenced form
a = [['-' for col in range(10)] for row in range(10)] 
print(a)

#If you wanted in refrenced form
a=[['-']*10]*10
print(a)
```

Example of not refrenced..

```
a = [['-' for col in range(10)] for row in range(10)] 
a[0][0]='change'
print(a)
```

**Output:-**

> [['change', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-',
> '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-',
> '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-',
> '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-',
> '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-',
> '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-',
> '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
> ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']]

Example of referenced..

```
a=[['-']*10]*10
a[0][0]='change'
print(a)
```

**Output:-**

> [['change', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['change',
> '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['change', '-', '-',
> '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['change', '-', '-', '-', '-',
> '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['change', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-',
> '-', '-', '-'], ['change', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-',
> '-'], ['change', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
> ['change', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['change',
> '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['change', '-', '-',
> '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']]

Answer (score 0):

You can use python itertools.repeat()

```
from itertools import repeat
list(repeat(["-"]*10, 10))
```

[image]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)